# SwiftUI and WidgetKit image alignment to the right

Tags: swift, swiftui, widgetkit

The code:

```
VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                    Image("Useful")
                        .resizable()
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: 105, height: 105)
                        .padding(.trailing, -60.0)
                }
```

The problem is that image is not at the side and has a small gap near the image and widget as shown in the photo.
[image: Widget Photo]

How to make this little gap disappear
:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understood your concern, here is possible solution

[image: demo]

```
var body: some View {
    Color.clear.overlay(
          Image("plant")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: 105, height: 105)
    , alignment: .bottomTrailing)
}
```